# using WebGL index buffers for drawing meshes

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

[3 index buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696182/3-index-buffers) asks a more difficult question, but I feel like their main problem boils down to mine: is there a way to use index buffers to visit the same vertex multiple times in WebGL rather than duplicating the vertices?
All I was able to find is using index buffers to associate textures, normals, etc. to vertices in a model. I wasn't able to find a way to use an index buffer to tell drawArrays the order in which to visit the vertices in a position array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use gl.drawElements and upload the buffer with your vertex indices to gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.

```
... upload vertex data to buffers, vertexAttribPointer them.

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indicesData.length/3, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL/Creating_3D_objects_using_WebGL for a full example.

Answer (score 0):

When you use indices, you can just double the indexes. However, this makes no sense to me as processing the same vertex data multiple times with the same global state, **results would be the same for each duplicate**.

What I suspect you really want to do is to make **multiple Draw calls** on the same vertex data with different uniforms.

1. Create vertex data/indices (if wanted) at startup
2. Each Frame, set global state A, call DrawElements/Array, set state B, call DrawElements/Array
3. From time to time, change vertex data (e.g. if objects are moving)..

As long as you don't change vertex data, there is just minor uploads to the gpu (*needing low bandwidth*).